# Cassandra Insert perfomance issue into a table with a map type

Tags: cassandra, bulkinsert, cql3

Hi I'm trying to understand this issue i'm having with inserting data using cql3 into a table with a map type. Usually i can insert data avg about 1000 iops per cql3 thread with no problem. Once i added the map type, the insert timed out after ~100,000 entries with this error: Unable to complete request: one or more nodes were unavailable. On multiple nodes(even across datacenter), i'm notcing that the cpu load is spiking unusually high during the insert.

The spec on each node is:
Cpu: 16 Core
Memory: 64GB

This is the test table schema i have set up.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id text,
    q text,
    g text,
    gt text,
    gi map<text,text>,
    ts timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC);

CREATE KEYSPACE testkeyspace WITH replication = {
    'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
    'DC1': '2',
    'DC2': '2'
};
```

Cassandra Version 1.2.4

Update:
At the moment we're just importing data from our other rdbms. About 100% of the time, we're either adding new rows or adding new elements to the map column. I'm aware of the restriction on the number of elements that a map column can have.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082963/bad-performance-when-writing-log-data-to-cassandra-with-timeuuid-as-a-column-nam/17123236#17123236

Comment: It would help to see an example of one of your insert statements. Are you writing new rows all the time, or are you modifying existing? How many elements are you adding to the map column?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few reports lately that performance when using CQL3 collections gets really bad, and it explains a few problems I've seen myself. I don't know exactly what is causing the problem and if it's the collections themselves or something else.

The most common thing people run into is that their schemas create hotspots. It's hard to tell from just looking at a `CREATE TABLE` statement if that is your problem, but if the number of distinct values for your partition key (the first item in the primary key) is low, you're constantly writing to the same node. Also, even if Cassandra handles rows of billions of rows in theory, having wide high traffic rows leads to lots of overhead when Cassandra continously has to compact them. If you also mix reads and writes Cassandra has to do a lot of digging through SSTables to materialize a row.

Please post more information about the inserts you're running, if you're writing new rows all the time, modifying existing rows, and especially how you work with those map columns -- are you adding new elements, removing elements? How many elements are expected to be in one of those map columns at any given time?

Another thing you can do is to run one or a few of your operations with tracing and see what Cassandra is doing (see http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tracing-in-cassandra-1-2 for how to enable tracing and analyze the results).

Comment: At the moment we're just importing data from our other rdbms. About 100% of the time, we're either adding new rows or adding new elements to the map column. I'm aware of the restriction on the number of elements that a map column can have. Let me try the tracing method to analyze the result.

Comment: So it looks like we're pushing the writes too hard. Seeing a lot of dropped mutation & pending mutationstage on the other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem when adding a map type column to my CF (Theo linked my related question above). I have used a workaround since, avoiding the map column type. Another user reported on [this issue on the cassandra mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201304.mbox/%3C5CDB66A8-441E-4612-84A2-D806C756BBD1@thelastpickle.com%3E) but the issue remained unsolved as well.

Some notes:

- the "uvrid" given in the primary key clause does not exist in the column definition.
- you might consider replacing the timestamp [with timeuuids to avoid collisions](http://www.rustyrazorblade.com/2012/10/cassandra-cql3-and-time-series-data-with-timeuuid/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually inserting entries into a Map type is actually an update. Inserts on collections have a performance impact.